# debug local asp.net is very slow with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am trying to run and debug my application using local Web server with VS 2008, it is very slow to load the web page. It's taking about 5 minutes to load the initial page. What could be wrong? I tried on IE and FireFox.

Comment: Given this information, almost _anything_ could be wrong.  Where are you finding the bottleneck between requesting the page and displaying it?  We can't step through your debugger for you.

Comment: What are your system parameters?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with requesting the page and displaying the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time compilation of your code does take some time - how big is the application? Subsequent loads should take less time. Have you tried setting breakpoints at the entry of your web app to see if it is *your* code that is slow?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is first time or subsequent loads. It's very slow. The same code is running on other machines. It's faster.

Comment: Other machines with the same hardware and software specs? Have you looked at available memory? A possible CPU hogging process unrelated to your app?

Comment: Try performance profiling it? http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/